# Nestjs setGlobalPrefix exclude option not working

Tags: javascript, nestjs, prefix, global-path

All my routes should have api prefix, except the .well-known route so I've added that path into the exclude option of the `setGlobalPrefix` method

```
  app.setGlobalPrefix('api', { exclude: ['.well-known'] });
```

I've also tried to add it like this

```
  app.setGlobalPrefix('api', { exclude: [{ path: '.well-known', method: RequestMethod.GET }] });
```

But it still works only works with API prefix

[image: With api prefix]

[image: Without api prefix]

Here is my controller

```
@Controller('.well-known')
export class WellKnownController {
  constructor(
    @Inject(
    CustomProviders.APPLE_APP_SITE_ASSOCIATION)
    private readonly appleAppSiteAssociationFile: object,
  ) {}

  @Get('apple-app-site-association')
  async getAppleAppSiteAssociation() {
    return this.appleAppSiteAssociationFile;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exclude does not work because it cannot match the path value in the route. The problem is solved when you make it the same as your path in the route as in the code block below.

**main.ts file**

```js
app.setGlobalPrefix('api', {
    exclude: [
      {
        path: '.well-known/apple-app-site-association',
        method: RequestMethod.GET,
      },
    ],
  });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).